# Difference between 着 正在　and 把

Tags: grammar

Is there a difference between these sentences?
Are they all grammatically correct?

我把作业写完了。
我正在写得完作业。
我写着作业到完了。

Comment: 我正在写得完作业。
正在 is the present tense.
得完 implies the future tense.
It's not a good idea to put two different tenses in one sentence in this way (one verb only).
我正在写作业(now) or 我写得完作业(in the future)

Comment: The 3rd one may be 我会持续写著作业，直到写完了。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your situation (comparing 著正在 and 把)

It would be "am having" and "have"

我(I) 著正在(am having) 完成(complete/completed) 我的(my) 工作(work)

I am having my work completed (Which means I am completing my work)

我(I) 把(have) 我的(my) 工作(work) 完成了(completed)

I have my work completed

我(I) 會(will) 把(have) 我的(my) 工作(work) 完成(completed)

著 正在 are both continuous tense, so we usually just use either one.

Example:

看(look) 著(ing)

正在(ing) 看(look)

The first example emphasis the action (look)

The second example emphasis the timing

Answer (score 2):

我把作业写完了。 This is correct. I've finished my homework.

我正在写得完作业。→ 我正在写作业。I'm doing my homework.

我写着作业到完了。→ 我一直把作业写到完为止。I've been doing my homework until it was done.

着 isn't used as much as people think, contrary to what grammar texts might explain. It's used more in written Chinese than in spoken Chinese, but that's just my opinion. Other natives might disagree.

Hope that helps. :)

Answer (score 1):

You should also put what you want to say in English.

我把作业写完了。 [OK】

我正在写得完作业。 
If you want to say ’I've almost finished my homework.‘
我就快要写完作业了。

我写着作业到完了。 [Not good and I can't see what you want to say.]

Answer (score 1):

我正在写作业.
我在写着作业.
我把作业写完了.
the first two sentence means that the thing is going on 
and the last sentence is thing is done.
if you want to know more about the 把 sentences and 被 sentences， you can check this video
http://www.hanbridgemandarin.com/course/demo/%E6%8A%8A-sentence-and-%E8%A2%AB-sentence